# Give radio button label from 2 column db

Tags: yii, radio-button, active-form

I have a Module table with these column

> ID_MODULE, NAMA_MODULE, ESTIMASI_HARGA, FLAG

I want to display NAMA_MODULE and ESTIMASI_HARGA on RadioButton. But I can only manage to display NAMA_MODULE with this code

```
<?php $items=ArrayHelper::map(Module::find()->where(['FLAG'=>1])->all(),'ID_MODULE',['NAMA_MODULE']) ?>
<?php echo $form->field($pMod, 'ID_MODULE', ['options' => ['style' => 'display:none', 'id' => 'pModule']])->inline()->checkboxList($items,$items)->label(false); ?>
```

Is it possible to give radio button a label with 2 column from DB with Yii?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$items = ArrayHelper::map(Module::find()->where(['FLAG'=>1])->all(),
'ID_MODULE',
    function($model) {
       return $model->NAMA_MODULE.'-'.$model->ESTIMASI_HARGA;
    }
);
```